# CSS positioning : inline image alignment issue

Tags: html, css, css-position

```
<div>
   <img class="top-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-png">
   <h1>I'm Rithik.</h1>
   <p>B.E. Information Technology(IT) Student</p>
   <img class="bottom-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-png">
</div>
```

If I define this div inside my webpage, the bottom-cloud image aligns itself just after the paragraph
whereas If I add another image just after the bottom cloud(which is bigger in size than the bottom cloud).

```
<img src="images/mountain.png" alt="mountain-png">
```

The cloud image also moves down inline with the new image I inserted. Shouldn't cloud image remain at its previous position and the new image just comes after this. I have attached screenshots for better understanding.
[image]

before adding another image.

[image]

After adding the mountain image why does the cloud also move down to align with the mountain?

Comment: Please add a demo link with your problem

Comment: where is your css? you also have a typo: `<\div>` which should be: `</div>`

Comment: How do I add a demo link? I am new to stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the 2 images to be on the same line, but aligned at the top instead of the bottom use `vertical-align: text-top;`

By default it is set to `baseline` which is why they are aligned at the bottom.

```css
img {
  vertical-align: text-top;
}

#img1 {
  width: 40%;
}
#img2 {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img id='img1' src='https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png'>
  <img id='img2' src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRP3y-tITlqjr7xjuWA4ooxpP-z8OtoeNqacg&usqp=CAU'>
</div>
```

### Why This Happens

The image here is in black and the area it is sitting within is in blue. When you have 1 image these are the same size, because the image is the only thing within the area.
[image: 1 image diagram]

When you have 2 images (set with their default value to `baseline`) the area that the images are sitting in expands to fit around both images/all the content within the line.
[image: 2 Images aligned to baseline]

Changing `vertical-align` to `text-top` means both the images move to the top of the area, like this:

[image: 2 images aligned to top]

In your example the area (blue box) is just the line that both the images are on, and it is working like this:

[image: Diagram to explain the website screenshot]

Whereas when you only had 1 image, the blue box was much smaller, since it was just the size of your smaller image.

[image: Diagram to explain the first website screenshot]

Comment: Ok. but why is this happening? If we add images or text together they all will align together to baseline?

Comment: when there was only one image it aligned itself just after the paragraph but when I added another image why it aligned itself along with other image and moved down?

Comment: I have added some diagrams, hopefully that helps to explain what is happening.

Comment: is this concept followed for a text and an image aligned together as well?

Comment: Yes it should, check out this page on w3schools about vertical-align https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp